# Mixed Content: The page at "url" was loaded over HTTPS but requested an insecure script the content must be served over HTTPS

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, https

I am facing the below mentioned issue which regarding the protocol related and mixed content and I also added the extension of the cross origin but it still not working me and after the lots of debuning I found the issue that is response.sendRedirect is returning the response in http insted of the https so that whenever I access that web page it showing me Not secure please find the below error and warnings

this request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

I also added the scrren shot of the server.xml

```
response.sendRedirect(url);
```

[image: example]

Comment: check out this link, [ask]

Comment: I'm  not sure how posting your server configuration is going to help. It is your code calling `response.sendRedirect(url);` What *exactly* if the value of `url`  and how do you get this? Are you behind a load balancer?